# and and or condition in single xml statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to construct a statement containing and and multiple or expressions in xml like

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="VAR1 and VAR1/text() != 'A' | 'B' | 'C'">
   <xsl:value-of select="$data"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>0.0</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

but its nt working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One solution, which avoids multiple comparisons is**:

`VAR1 and VAR1/text()[not(contains('A+B+C', .))]`

where the `+` string is guaranteed not to be contained in `VAR1/text()` (if "+" doesn't satisfy this requirement, substitute "+" with a string that does)

**Do note** that there is a likely logical error in the question:

`x != 'A' or x != 'B' or x != 'C'`

**is always true**

Most probably you wanted:

`x != 'A' and x != 'B' and x != 'C'`